# ASCII to Binary Representation (Big Endian)

Tags: c, string, parsing, binary, endianness

I am writing a function that converts an ascii string to its binary representation in big endian.

Here is my code:

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_strs; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            char c = sep_str[i][j];
            for (int k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
                putchar((c & (1 << k)) ? '1' : '0');
                count++;
            }

            if (count == 32) {
                putchar('\n');
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to pad each character to 32 bits. So for example, a space is `0x20` --> `1000000`. I want to write it out as `00000000000000000000000001000000` and have each 32-bit binary number on a separate line. What would I change in my code?

I tried changing the `for k` look to start from 32 but that obviously did not work...

Comment: Well, if you've got something that prints eight bits, and you want to zero pad it, the obvious way would be to first print twenty-four zeros. Then of course get rid of all the count stuff and always put the newline. Is this homework?

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of your variables. Have you got `num_strs` strings, stored in `sep_str`? Is each one 5-character long?

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("0000000000000000000000000"); // 25 zeros, leaving 7 bits for ASCII
for (int k = 6; k >= 0; k--) {
    putchar((c & (1 << k)) ? '1' : '0');
}
putchar('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add 24 0's before each byte. One way would be to actually go through all 32 bits but only check for 1's on the last eight:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_strs; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        char c = sep_str[i][j];
        for (int k = 31; k >= 0; k--) {
            putchar((k <= 7 && c & (1 << k)) ? '1' : '0');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

- `sep_str` is an array of null-terminated strings
- you want 4-byte groups printed as 32-bits (rather that 1 byte with 24 extra zeros in front)
- You want padding at the *beginning* rather than the end

..then you could look at the following.  If any of those assumptions is wrong, there are lots of comments and you should be able to modify as needed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_strs; i++) { /* for each string... */
  int len = strlen(sep_str[i]);        /* get length */
  int n = len % 4;                     /* (4 - n) = # of bytes of padding */
  switch (n) {                         /* print leading padding */
    case 1: fputs("00000000",stdout);    /* because of case fall-through, we print */
    case 2: fputs("00000000",stdout);    /*  8 '0's up to 3 times, depending on the */
    case 3: fputs("00000000",stdout);    /*  amount of padding needed */
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {      /* For each char up to len... */
    for (int k = 0x80; k; k >>=1) {      /* For each bit (k has the tested bit set) */
                                           /* print 1 if bit set in char, or 0 */
      putchar(((unsigned char)(sep_str[i][j]) & k) ? '1' : '0');
    }
    if (!(++n % 4))                      /* If multiple of 4 bytes written... */ 
      putchar('\n');                       /* ..add a linefeed */
  }
}
```